# Prove that for every positive whole number $n$, there exists a number $m_{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Use mathematical induction for the following.
Prove that for every positive whole number $n$, there exists a number $m_{n}$ such that  $m_{n}$ has $n$ digits in its decimal representation, all of its digits belong to $\left \{ 1, 2 \right \}$ and  $m_{n}$ is divisible by $2^{n}$.

Comment: What attempts have you done so far?

Comment: Did you try to find a few.  If $n=1$ you need $m_n=1$.  If $n=2$ we need number divisible by $4$ with only the digits $1,2$.  So that be $m_2=12$. If $n_2$ we must have a number divisible by $8$ so we have $112=8\times 14$.  If $n=4$ we need $16$ divisible.  it even so the last digit needs to be $2$.  It divisible by $4$ so the last two digits can't be $22$ so the last to digits must be $12$.  It's divisible by $8$ but $12$ isn't so the third digit.... well, hmmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R_n= m_n \cdot 2^{-n}$

The assertion is equivalent to saying that for every $n$ there exists an $m_n$ such that $R_n$ is an integer.

This is clearly true for $n=2$ for which $m_2=12\;\text{ and }\;R_2=3$

for $n=k$ assume that $R_k$ is an integer

Then we can form $m_{k+1}$ in two ways ...

$$m^{(1)}_{k+1} = 10^k + m_k
\\[1em] = 2^k 5^k + 2^kR_k = 2^k(5^k + R_k)$$
Since $5^k$ is always odd, $m^{(1)}_{k+1}$  will be  divisible by $2^{k+1}$ if and only if $R_k$ is odd
$$m^{(2)}_{k+1} = 2\cdot10^k + m_k
\\[1em] = 2^{k+1} 5^k + 2^kR_k = 2^k(2\cdot5^k + R_k)$$
Since $2 \cdot 5^k$ is always even, $m^{(2)}_{k+1}$  will be
divisible by $2^{k+1}$ if and only if $R_k$ is even.

Since $R_k$ is an integer it must be either even or odd so either $m^{(1)}_{k+1}$  or $m^{(2)}_{k+1}$  will be divisible by $2^{k+1}$